# How many ways are there to group a sequence into maximal number of contiguous subsequences of given length?

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have a sequence $S_q$ of length $q$ and we want to group it into $m$ contiguous subsequences of length $n$. Apparently $$m=\left\lfloor\frac{|S_q|}{n}\right\rfloor.$$ My question is how many ways (denote as $h$) are there to do so? To make myself clear I will use $$S_6=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$$ as an example. If $n=6$ then $m=1$, and there is only one way ($h=1$) to do it. since only contiguous subsequence of length $6$ is $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$. Now if $n=5$ then $m=1$ still but $h=2$ since $(1,2,3,4,5),(2,3,4,5,6)$ are both valid. Further $n=4$ then $m=1$ and $h=3$. However if $n=3$ then $m=2$ but $h=1$, for we can only do $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$, and so on. For fixed $q,n$, what would be a formula for $h$?

Comment: Equivalently, the number of $m$-subsets of $\{1,\cdots,q\}$ whose elements are all pairwise $\ge n$ apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r := q - mn$ the number of elements which are not grouped. These $r$ elements can be distributed in the $m+1$ "holes" between (and before/behind) the subseqences. So there are 
$$ h = \binom{(m+1)+r-1}{r} = \binom{m + r}m $$
ways.

Comment: I just came up with this myself... But many thanks!